# FHIR CodableConcept - All elements must be from ValueSet - Writing Profile Differential

Tags: hl7-fhir

I want to create a profile from base `Observation`, in that all `code` elements must be from the `ValueSet`. For example:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Observation",
  "id": "example",
  "meta": {
    "profile": ["http://my.own.profile/StructureDefinition/custom-observation-profile"]
  }

  ...

  "code": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://loinc.org",
        "code": "8867-4",
        "display": "Body Weight"
      },
      {
        "system": "http://loinc.org",
        "code": "9843-4",
        "display": "Body Weight"
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

All the elements from `code.coding` should be from a valueset, lets say `http://my.value.set`

In the differential, I have the following:

```
      {
        "id": "Observation.code",
        "path": "Observation.code",
        "short": "Body Weight",
        "type": [
          {
            "code": "CodeableConcept"
          }
        ],
        "binding": {
          "strength": "required",
          "description": "All LOINC  values whose SCALE is DOC in the LOINC database and the HL7 v3 Code System NullFlavor concept 'unknown'",
          "valueSet": "http://my.value.set"
        }
      },
```

But this one is validating only the first element in the list. It does not validate the other ones. It ignores even if they are invalid.

The list can be `1..*`, and I want all of them should be from the `valueSet`.

How do I write differential for this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expectation when there's a required binding on a CodeableConcept is that *one* of the CodeableConcept.coding repetitions must come from the binding.  There's no requirement that the others must - and the primary use for additional codings is that you don't *want* them to be from the same value set.  The purpose of additional codings is to convey other codes from other code systems that also convey the same meaning (so that other recipients of the instance who might not necessarily recognize the code preferred by your profile can still find a code they recognize - and also so that the 'original' coding can be retained in cases where that isn't from the bound value set).

If you truly want to force all CodeableConcept.coding repetitions to be from a single value set (strongly discouraged and likely to impede interoperability), you could declare a binding on Observation.code.coding.

Comment: Wow! Thats something I did not know. Thanks much! Just out of curiosity, if I still want to force, how do I define binding for `Observation.code.coding` so that other elements confirms to the ValueSet?

Comment: Just define the binding at the Observation.code.coding level instead on the Observation.code level.  (But please don't.  The whole point of having multiple Codings is to retain original codes and to allow implementations to support multiple profiles with a single instance.  Constraining out data you don't want that others might want is always bad interoperability practice.)

Comment: Thanks much. I guess my understanding was wrong on constraining all the codes. I will not be doing it. :-)